# How to stop v4l2-ctl streaming?

Tags: linux, interrupt, v4l2, v4l

Suppose I run `v4l2-ctl --stream-mmap=3 --stream-to=/dev/null`, how to stop recording without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for interrupt, from another shell console for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless they have added a better functionality, you will have to simply signal the process from outside.

Either `v4l2-ctl ... & V4L2_CTL_PID=$!` and `kill -TERM $V4L2_CTL_PID`

or maybe simply `killall v4l2-ctl`.